# Can a comprehensive list of adult keywords be found anywhere?

Tags: keyword, spam, spam-prevention, blacklist

I am looking for a comprehensive list of English adult keywords to be used on my website in a spam blacklist to prevent users from entering inappropriate keywords.

A text file listing or web link of listing would suffice

thanks for your help

Comment: Incidentally, you might want to have a read of [Obscenity Filters: Bad Idea, or Incredibly Intercoursing Bad Idea?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea.html)

Comment: I have found this listing:  http://www.mattfacer.com/new/sweary/swear.sql  i will use this as the last resort, unless someone else can provide a more comprehensive list. - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this listing:

http://mattfacer.com/new/sweary/swear.sql

Answer (score 1):

A quick search in google gives the following results:

http://ravisrants.com/2007/03/27/bad-words-to-blacklist-in-your-blogs-comments/

Comment: Neither of these links provide a comprehensive list of adult only keywords, but rather a short list of adult and spam words. Im not sure i would want to filter out words such as "jewelry", "finland", "honda",  "insurance", "slots", "keno".  Although they could be spam words, they could also, not be. I am more interested in filtering out ADULT related words.  - Thanks